# Paragraph execution in zeppelin goes to pending state after some time and hadoop application status for zeppelin is finished

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am using zeppelin from the last 3 months and noticed this strange problem recently. Everyday morning I had to restart zeppelin for it to work or else the paragraph execution will go to pending state and never run. I tried to dig deeper to check what is the problem. The state of the zeppelin application in yarn is finshed. I tried to check the log and it shows the below error. Couldn't make out anything out of it.

```
2017-06-28 22:04:08,986 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 56876 for container-id container_1498627544571_0001_01_000002: 1.2 GB of 4 GB physical memory used; 4.0 GB of 20 GB virtual memory used
2017-06-28 22:04:08,995 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 56787 for container-id container_1498627544571_0001_01_000001: 330.2 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.4 GB of 5 GB virtual memory used
2017-06-28 22:04:09,964 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1498627544571_0001_01_000002 is : 1
2017-06-28 22:04:09,965 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_1498627544571_0001_01_000002 and exit code: 1
ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-06-28 22:04:09,972 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch.
2017-06-28 22:04:09,972 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Container id: container_1498627544571_0001_01_000002
2017-06-28 22:04:09,972 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exit code: 1
```

I am the only user in that environment and no one else is using it. There isn't any process running at that time as well. Couldn't understand why it is happening.